# 10 second delay on ssh operations

Tags: ssh, debian, sshfs, beaglebone, beagleboard

After doing various things to my BeagleBone Black, I noticed it started giving me a ten second delay on every SSH operation, including SSHFS file transfers.  But once it was connected (after that initial delay), the connection operated normally.

Debian-7.9-console-armhf, Windows 7 host.

Answer (score 2):

I put `/etc/resolv.conf` back to the default value, and got immediate response again. (No reboot or restart required.)

```
nameserver 0.0.0.0
```

(I had put a value in there to get it on the internet for loading packages.)  WireShark showed me it was spending that ten seconds doing ARP requests for its gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/ssh/ssh_config and your ~/.ssh/config files and see if you have VerifyHostKeyDNS set to "yes" or "ask". If it is, just comment it out or change it to "no". A quick check to confirm this is the problem before changing the file(s) is to use the following option on the ssh command line:

```
    -o "VerifyHostKeyDNS=no"
```

See more at https://keithstechblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/ssh-delays/.